# If $X$ is a random variable and $Y= X^2$, how do we obtain the relationship $f_Y(y) dy = f_X(\sqrt{y}) dx + f_X(-\sqrt{y}) dx$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X$ is a random variable and $Y= X^2$, then the way the density $f_Y(y)$ is related to the density of $f_X(x)$ is through the equation:

$$
f_Y(y) dy = f_X(\sqrt{y}) dx +  f_X(-\sqrt{y}) dx
$$

I am unable to derive this equation. I understand that:

$$
P\left(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}\right) = P(X \leq \sqrt{y})-P(X \leq -\sqrt{y})
$$

but I am not sure how to get the above equation. I know more fundamentally that:

$$
f_Y(y) dy = f_X(x) dx 
$$

but even this equation I do not see an intuitive reason why it holds. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: @Max From what I see, is it just basically multiplying $\frac{dy}{dy}$ on the left hand side of the middle equation and multiplying $\frac{dx}{dx}$ on the right hand side? Can you please explain how to get the derivative of $P(X \leq -\sqrt{y})$? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have derived that

$$ F_Y(y) = \Pr\{Y \leq y\} = \Pr\{X \leq \sqrt{y}\} - \Pr\{X \leq -\sqrt{y}\}$$

Differentiating both sides with respect to $y$,

$$ f_Y(y) = \frac {1} {2\sqrt{y}}f_X(\sqrt{y}) 
+ \frac {1} {2\sqrt{y}}f_X(-\sqrt{y})$$

Usually when you obtain this result it is suffice for you to do the transformation work. In case you must need the result with the differentials, multiply both side by $dy$,

$$ f_Y(y)dy = f_X(\sqrt{y})\frac {1} {2\sqrt{y}}dy
+ f_X(-\sqrt{y})\frac {1} {2\sqrt{y}}dy$$

And the final result stated 
$$ f_Y(y)dy = f_X(x)dx $$
is the fundamental result of change of variable. It means that the (infinitesimal) probability should be unchanged after transformation.